# How to grab remote public key and store in Apollo graphql server periodically?

Tags: node.js, firebase, graphql, jwt, apollo

I have run an Apollo graphql server. I want to verify JWT sent by Firebase client. According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) document we can fetch public keys to verify. It also gives `max-age` until which we can store the key.  I use Auth0-nodejs for JWT verification. My problem is how do I periodically fetch this public key and store in nodejs variable in Apollo server so that I don't have to fetch keys from firebase for every request in the apollo server.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
schema, context: ({ req }) => {
const token = req.headers.authorization;
const user = getAuthorizedUser(token);
return { user };
}
});

server.listen();
```

Here getAuthorizedUser(token) needs to grab the public keys from remote server  every time on new request. This may slow down my app. I am not sure how can I periodically fetch data from remote server and use it for every request on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just fetch them lazily. Something like:

```
let keys
let expiresAt = 0

async function getPublicKeys () {
  if (expiresAt < Date.now()) {
    try {
      const { maxAge, publicKeys } = await getKeysFromFirebase()
    catch (e) {
      // Handle being unable to fetch the keys from Google -- either retry or throw
    }
    expiresAt = (maxAge * 1000) + Date.now() - arbitraryPadding
    keys = publicKeys
  }
  return keys
}
```

Barring that, you could have your application refetch them before they expire using `setTimeout` -- you would just need to ensure that your timer is cleared when the process exits. You could also set up a cron job that would just periodically write the keys to file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for point me to the right direction. I am somewhat new to graphql and node. Will this code re fetch keys regularly ? Also will the `keys` be accessible all the requests so that I can verify all the incomin requests?

Comment: You would call (and await) `getPublicKeys` from inside your context function. On every request, the function would check if the keys are expired. If they are not expired, it would return what's in memory (the `keys` variable). If they are expired, it would get the keys from Firebase (you have to supply this bit of code yourself) and then update the `keys` and `expiresAt` variables based on the response from Firebase. And *then* it would finally return the value of `keys`, which has now been updated.

Comment: Thank you. Finally I got it to work. I added callback function while calling `getPublicKeys()` and it finally working as desired.